# Passing one type of data to different places (retrofit)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm new to retrofit and I have a question. I want to create only one call to server and then use downloaded data in different places in my App. I'm using viewPager with few fragments and each fragment will need same data from DataResponse class to create different Views. What is the best way to do that and how it would look like? This is how my retrofit class look like. Thanks in advance!

```
public class ApiClientFactory {

    public static final String baseURL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/";

    public ApiClient createApiClient(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);
    }
}

public interface ApiClient {

    @GET("query")
    Call<DataResponse> getData(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have an Activity which contains the ViewPager. In activity's onCreate() method you can make that request. When you receive a response you can build your adapter (FragmentPagerAdapter) and pass your DataResponse there. In adapter you build fragments and set arguments with DataResponse.

The sample code:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...//

        makeRequest(); //Implement this method to get Data
    }

    //When the response is received call this method
    private void onResponse(DataResponse response) {
        //create your adapter 
        mAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(response, getSupportFragmentManager());

        //don't forget to set adapter to the ViewPager
    }

    static class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        DataResponse mResponse;

        CustomPagerAdapter(DataResponse response, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mResponse = response;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //create your fragments and set arguments

            return CustomFragment.instance(mResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1; //number of your fragments
        }
    }
}

public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_RESPONSE = "key_response";

    public static CustomFragment instance(DataResponse response) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(KEY_RESPONSE, response);
        CustomFragment f = new CustomFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View root, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(root, savedInstanceState);
        DataResponse response = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_RESPONSE);

        //do with the response whatever you want
    }
}
```

Make sure DataResponse implements Parcelable interface.